# How to show data from a (MySQL) DB on Joomla (3.0) user member page?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I just started to understand the Joomla (3.) and the MVC concept (I have some PHP/JavaScript/HTML programing experience). I installed the version with some example data.

I'm trying to figure out how to change the contents of the user member page? (e.g., the page the user sees after logging in - see example in attached picture). Instead of the current shown article (starting with 'Getting started') in the attached example I want to show some data from the database.

I believe the way forward is developing a MVC plugin (or module of component?) -  for which I read through some of the Joomla documentation.

Two specific questions:

1. How to link/integrate this plugin to the related position in memberpage? (I was looking for a way at the Joomla admin site  to link the plugin to the relevant position in the template of the memberpage, but could not find this)
2. Is there any example code for this kind of basic functionality?

Appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a specific example of what data you want to show.  What you want to do is very achievable but without specifics any answers will be as general as your question.

Answer (score 0):

So the article is, in fact, "some data from  the database."  I think what you mean is you want to show "some specific data" from the database, but can you give us an idea of what the data consists of? For example is is content you created ina component? Or something else? Also,  you can configure the page to select where the redirect after login goes. If that's all you are asking for, just do that for example in the login module options or in the menu link options for com_users login view..